# Calling JavaScript method in a particular scope

Tags: javascript, dojo, scope

Dear All,
I'm using dojo.declare to create classes in JavaScript. In one of the methods, I've an AJAX request. In the load method of that request, I need to execute certain methods.These methods are actually methods of the class that was created using dojo.declare. I tried to execute the method using `this`. But it gave me method not found error. So I used `dojo.hitch(this,testMethod)` to invoke it. It worked fine. Now the problem is I've lot of other methods also inside `testMethod()` which internally calls other methods of my JavaScript class. It is really a pain to have dojo.hitch() everywhere. Is there any work around for this.

```
    dojo.declare("TestClass",null,{

    getData:function(url){
    dojo.xhrGet({
      url:url,
      load: function (response){
        dojo.hitch(scope of the current object,testMethod(response))    
      },
      error:function(){

      }
    });
    },
    testMethod:function(response){
    //calls testMethod2. I think I can use dojo.hitch(this,testMethod3) to call it.
    //but I wanted to avoid doing it every time.
    },
    testMethod2:function(){
    //calls testMethod3
    },
    testMethod3:function(){
    //can call other methods.
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that execution scope was lost in this code:

```
load: function (response){
        dojo.hitch(this,testMethod(response))   
      },
```

I made small changes in your code. Now it should work properly.

```
dojo.declare("TestClass",null,{

        getData:function(url){
        dojo.xhrGet({
          url:url,
          load: dojo.hitch(this,this.testMethod),
          error:function(){

          }
        });
        },
        testMethod:function(response){
           this.testMethod2();
        },
        testMethod2:function(){
           this.testMethod3();
        },
        testMethod3:function(){
        //can call other methods.
        }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Ander, Thanks for the reply. I've one question. In load method, "this" refers to window object. But there is no testMethod for window object. Could you please explain the reason it should work?

Comment: Why do you think that "this" refers to window object? It should refers to the instance of "TestClass" class.

Comment: dojo.xhrGet() is executed in window scope. I checked it in Firebug also, by setting a breakpoint there.

Comment: http://pastehtml.com/view/1dgmiua.html - check source of this page. You can find example of the use of your class.

Comment: Thank you very much Ander for the help. I was wrong there. AJAX call is made in widow scope, but when we set as mentioned in your example, it calls in that particular scope. I think it should be load: dojo.hitch(this,"testMethod"). Method name should be in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical context problem.  You are passing an uncontexted function as a property of a configuration hash, which is passed as argument to dojo.xhrGet.

dojo.hitch is exactly the right construct to add a context to a function. Another way is to simply use a closure. Is there any reason why you can't do:

```
var me = this;
dojo.xhrGet({
    url:url,
    load: function(response) {
        me.testMethod(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
   url:url,
   load: dojo.hitch(this, "testMethod"),
   error:function(){

   }
});
```

Your way worked as well, but it saves you a few bytes and is just cleaner to use the method name as a string. Hitch will automatically pass the arguments for you.